# Add onkeyup function to a DOM element with text arguments in the function using setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, syntax

Im trying to add a function using setAttribute to a DOM element executing all of this in my WordPress php file (functions.php).

This is my HTML element:

`<input type="text" class="input-text " name="bank_account" id="bank_account">`

And this is my PHP function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'addJsInCheckout');

function addJsInCheckout() {
    echo '<script>
            let = bank_account = document.getElementById("bank_account");
            bank_account.setAttribute("maxlength", "23");
            bank_account.setAttribute("onkeyup", "limitTextCount("bank_account", "divcount", "23")");
         </script>';
}
```

**Information to note:**

1.- I correctly set the `maxlength` attribute in my code.

2.- If I remove the quotes and add the parameters as a number, it works, but not as text (`bank_account.setAttribute("onkeyup", "limitTextCount(bank_account, divcount, 23)");`).

On the other hand, I have tried doing it in the following two ways:

- `bank_account.setAttribute("onkeyup", "limitTextCount("'bank_account'", "'divcount'", "'23'")");`
- `bank_account.setAttribute("onkeyup", "limitTextCount('"bank_account"', '"divcount"', '"23"')");`

But both ways give me an error and I get an error:

`syntax error, unexpected '"bank_account"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

As a last thing, I simply tested:

- `bank_account.setAttribute("onkeyup", "limitTextCount("bank_account", "divcount", "23")");`

And despite I don't get any syntax error, the function is not added to the element.

Can someone give me a hand? I don't know how to tell it to take my parameters as text.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing quotes up. The easiest way to solve this is to just get out of PHP mode, write your HTML which will `echo` automatically, and then switch back.

**Edit**

Instead of using `setAttribute` for events, it is probably a safer option to use `addEventListener`.

```php
function addJsInCheckout()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        let = bank_account = document.getElementById("bank_account");
        bank_account.setAttribute("maxlength", "23");
        
        bank_account
            .addEventListener(
                'onkeyup',
                () => {
                    limitTextCount('23', '23', '23');
                });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but only with numbers. If I want to add text like: `bank_account.setAttribute("onkeydown", "limitTextCount('bank_account', 'divcount, 23);";` Im still getting the same syntac error. Thank you for your answer btw!

Comment: In that very specific example, you are missing a single quote at the end of `'divcount`. It should be `'divcount'`

Comment: Yes, you right, I just rewrite it. I updated my question to clarify more. Thank you again

Comment: @Caín, I've updated my answer. I wasn't really reading the actual HTML/JavaScript earlier, but now that I see that you are using events, it is probably best to use `addEventListener` to add them.